# Revived NPC will not follow me out of cave

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I just finished a quest in Broken Oar Grotto. I have a normal Follower and a NPC (Chief Yamarz) I revived with Raise Thrall.

I am leaving the cave and my Follower comes out just fine, but my dead NPC will not leave the cave. He will follow me around like normal in the cave, but not transverse areas. Nor does Fast Traveling fix this.

Why? How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[According to the text at the bottom of this UESPWiki page, it's a bug.](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Reanimate)

If you have the PC version you can work around it via the console.

*Reanimated or Thralls may get stuck in some cells (locations) and may not go outside with the player. To fix that go back inside and find your thrall, open the Console and target your thrall (you should see a number RefID), do not click on anything else and close the console, go outside and open the console again to issue a command moveto player, close console. Your thrall should stand next to you.*

Answer (score 2):

The same thing happened to me, so I beat her up until she started hitting me back, then left the cave and fast-traveled. She was then with me (and wasn't trying to kill me). This should work on Xbox 360 and PS3.